# Проблема с кросс-доменным запросом

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, get

### node.js сервер:

```
var express = require('express');

var app = express();

app.get('/', function(req, res) {

     res.sendFile('index.html');

});

app.listen(8080);
```

### index.html:

```
<html>
 <script> 
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open('GET', 'http://yandex.com', true);
  xhr.onload = function() {
     document.write( this.responseText );
  }

  xhr.send();
</script></html>
```

### Oшибка:

### [image]

В чем проблема?

- Браузер - yandex
- ОС - Windows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Кроссдоменные запросы запрещает браузер в целях безопасности.
Используй [jsonp](https://learn.javascript.ru/xhr-crossdomain) для этих целей